# Clip path border colour

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

Hi there I've successfully clipped a path to an svg shape and made it scale using the docs I found online.

However I'm attempting to add a border to the clip path and having no luck. I don't want to overlay this clip and add padding as I want transparancy.

Here is the code I've been using and the effect I'm trying to re-create is attached in the image.

Thanks in advance!

```
<svg 
    height="0" 
  width="0"
    viewBox="0 0 198.6 51.6"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Assets" fill="none">
            <defs>
            <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.00503524672
, 0.01937984496)">
        <path class="st0" d="M176.9,51.1H7.7c-4,0-7.2-3.2-7.2-7.2V7.7c0-4,3.2-7.2,7.2-7.2h183.1c4,0,7.2,3.2,7.2,7.2v22.2
    c0,1.9-0.8,3.8-2.1,5.1L182,49C180.7,50.4,178.8,51.1,176.9,51.1z"></path>
        </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </g>
</svg>

<style>
    .btn_b {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
    clip-path: url(#myClip);
    }
</style>
```

[example of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7SvV.png)

Comment: A clip is just that. What's inside is rendered, what's outside isn't. There's no such thing as a border.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot put a border on that follows the clip-path you can get the same sort of effect using background images on pseudo elements.

Here's a simple example where the black portion is just a smaller after pseudo element but clipped the same as the background provided by the before pseudo element.

```css
.btn_b {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 20vmin;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}

button::before,
button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

button::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, cyan, magenta);
}

button::after {
  top: 1vmin;
  left: 1vmin;
  width: calc(100% - 2vmin);
  height: calc(100% - 2vmin);
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn_b"></button>
<svg height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 198.6 51.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="Assets" fill="none">
            <defs>
            <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.00503524672
, 0.01937984496)">
        <path class="st0" d="M176.9,51.1H7.7c-4,0-7.2-3.2-7.2-7.2V7.7c0-4,3.2-7.2,7.2-7.2h183.1c4,0,7.2,3.2,7.2,7.2v22.2
    c0,1.9-0.8,3.8-2.1,5.1L182,49C180.7,50.4,178.8,51.1,176.9,51.1z"></path>
        </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this but it doesnt achieve what we're after. 

So I'm looking to get the background to be transparent not solid - this possible?

Comment: Ah, sorry I thought you wanted what was shown.  What do you mean by background? Are you wanting the multi colored edging but the black bit to be transparent (showing what is right underneath that whole element)?

Comment: Yeah idea would be for the black bit to be transparent and only the clip path border to be filled